# Outlook: save existing search query as "Search Folder"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

In Outlook When I **already** have a search query that is displaying results on screen in the email list pane, how do I save this EXISTING search query as a "Search Folder".

i.e. Without starting again from "New Search Folder" menu item.

I'm expecting to find a button like "Save this EXISTING search query as a Search Folder".

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, create the folder in your Outlook, then do a search query. Select one message in the result output, hold it and type Ctrl+A. Right-click and move them to the new created folder.

Comment: "Search Folders" are dynamic virtual folders that display the results of a search query.  Manually moving emails to real normal folder does not relate to "Search Folders".   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5

Comment: There is not a such bottom in Outlook client, except creating a customized search folder.